# Google reCAPTCHA does not accept this submission. Try again please, or contact to Site support services

Tags: 7, users, captcha

I have installed [Google reCAPTCHA](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_recaptcha) on my local Drupal 7 site and have configured the keys appropriately and set it to run only on the registration form.

I keep getting the error:

> Google reCAPTCHA does not accept this submission. Try again please, or
>   contact to Site support services.

See screenshot below:
[image]

I'm not sure why this is happening, I have tried both on my local server and on a hosted production site and I get the same error message.

Anyone know why this is? Or is there an alternative way I could prevent bots from creating spam registrations?

Comment: Did you forget to check the "I'm not a robot" box?

Comment: @choster Cmon now you're pushing it. I did not forget to check that.

Comment: you could try Image captcha instead of this recaptcha.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. Did you figure out a fix?